# No method named `join` found for AsRef<Path>

Tags: rust

I have a function that takes `AsRef<Path>` as an argument and looks like this

```
fn test<P: AsRef<std::path::Path>>(path: P) {
    path.join("13123123");
}
```

When I compile that, it gives me the following error

```
error[E0599]: no method named `join` found for type `P` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:2:10
  |
2 |     path.join("13123123");
  |          ^^^^
```

Comment: The compiler knows that `P` has type `AsRef`, and nothing else. You must first call the `as_ref` method to have a reference to the path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=80c8ce4b62ad8b730958d3f13d211950&version=stable):

```
path.as_ref().join("13123123")
```

see:

```
fn main() {
    let path = std::path::Path::new("./foo/bar/");
    test(path);
}

fn test<P: AsRef<std::path::Path>>(path: P) {
    println!("{:?}", path.as_ref().join("13123123"));
}
```

Output:

```
"./foo/bar/13123123"
```

See the [documentation for `AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html).

Comment: This answer would be improved if instead of only giving the solution it explained *why* the original didn't work as intended.